# How to derive any of the inner classes having count > 0 using linq or other approach

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, collections

How to derive any of the inner list of classes having count > 0 using linq  or other approach

ParentClass

ParentClass contains 10 inner classess - ChildClass1, ChildClass2, ChildClass3,...ChildClass10

class

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public List<ChildClass1> ChildClass1 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildClass2> ChildClass2 { get; set; }
    .
    .
    public List<ChildClass10> ChildClass10 { get; set; }
}
```

I having ParentClassObj from which how can I derive any of the inner class having count > 0.

I have one solution but it is not feasible to check for all 10 inner list of classes which is as below

```
if(!(ParentClassObj.ChildClass1.Any() && ParentClassObj.ChildClass2.Any() ...)
{
  // return not found
}
```

Is there any optimized solution using Linq  or other approach to derive. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your class and I think there is no better way to use linq but you can try reflaction

Comment: I have added the class in the question.

Comment: @MichaelMao, Other than Linq also is fine if it is a better solution that what I had in my question. Thanks

Comment: You can try reflection like @MichaelMao suggested, but you might need to reconsider your class design. 
It is hard to tell what you try to achieve with this class, but can it be possible to have the child classes derive from a common interface and store them all in one list?

Comment: @L01NL, can you help further how to achieve with reflection. Thanks

Comment: could you define "optimized solution", Your Linq looks optimized. If it about having less lines of code, maybe ParentClass could expose a mthode that does that. From an optimisation perspective, reflexion is slow.  any and count in the lastest C# will be faster than Count() on an IEnumerable, as they will acces the Count paramater of the icollection instead of counting

Comment: @User I thoudht `ChildClass1` has inherited from `ParentClass`. sorry

Comment: Why are you having to do this? What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you mean to say any or all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection way. Please see the `IsAllChildCountsMoreThanZero` method and change to what you want.

```
        public class ParentClass
        {
            public List<ChildClass1> ChildClass1 { get; set; }
            public List<ChildClass2> ChildClass2 { get; set; }
            public List<ChildClass10> ChildClass10 { get; set; }

            public bool IsAllChildCountsMoreThanZero()
            {
                foreach (var prop in typeof(ParentClass).GetProperties())
                {
                    var propType = prop.PropertyType;

                    if (propType.IsGenericType && (propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)))
                    {
                        var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(this, null);
                        if (propertyValue == null) return false;
                        var listPropertyValue = (IList)propertyValue;
                        if (listPropertyValue.Count == 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Given that the `class` is defined at compile time, a nice optimization might be a `static` variable set to `typeof(ParentCLass).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)).ToList()` so you don't reflect over the same class every call. It might also be nice to filter by desired property name pattern.